# Oracle Result Set: Duplicate Column Consuming Additional Memory?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

While analyzing a generated SQL-Statement I asked myself if it consumes unnecessary memory if a column in the result gets repeated. The framework repeates some of the columns based on the need. The values are accessed via index so if this is a real problem, it should be addressed.

So if you know for sure, please provide your oppinion on that issue.

Example:

`SELECT myTable.ID, myTable.Name, myTable.ID, myTable.name FROM MyTable myTable`

Is this example consuming twice the memory when compared to
`SELECT myTable.ID, myTable.Name FROM MyTable myTable` or is it internally implemented that it maps each column virtually to a single certain column containing the real values?

The question is for Oracle 12 only since it is what we are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't, and this is in fact pretty easy to test for yourself.

```
SQL> create table foo(bar varchar2(4000));
Table created.
SQL> insert into foo(bar) values(rpad('x',4000,'x'));
1 row created.
SQL> commit ;
Commit complete.

SQL> set autotrace traceonly statistics
SQL> select bar from foo;

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
       ...
       4549  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client

SQL> select bar,bar from foo;

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
       ...
       8617  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client

SQL> select bar,bar,bar,bar from foo;

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
      ...
      16765  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
```

Now I've never seen a scenario where this actually matters - the test above is pretty extreme.

That being said, Oracle does do some form of compression but for (some) cases when the same column has the same value in consecutive rows. e.g.

```
SQL> select bar from foo 
     union all select bar from foo
     union all select bar from foo;

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
       ...
       8608  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
```

(Adding another copy of `bar` only adds a few bytes.)